# Rigorous error bounds for `NIntegrate`

Tags: numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision

Suppose I want to numerically evaluate an integral of the form
$$\int_{-\infty} ^\infty f(x) \mathrm{d}x $$
with error not exceeding some positive bound $\epsilon$. Is there a way to do this using `NIntegrate`? What I would normally do is increase `WorkingPrecision` until the sought number of digits stabilizes, but I know it's not rigorous.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by rigorous? If you ask a mathematician you will get a different answer than what an engineer will tell you.

Comment: @george2079 I want the statement “the absolute error in the integration is less than $\epsilon$” to be mathematically true.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for `NIntegrate`, you can do `NIntegrate[f[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity},AccuracyGoal->n]` where `n` is the number of digits of accuracy you want.

Comment: Alternatively, `PrecisionGoal`, depends on what you (the OP) need. `PrecisionGoal` has some problems if the actual value is zero.